# How to keep old values with ajax in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have a section in my Product for add new attributes :

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputAttribute" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Attributes</label>

     <div class="col-sm-10">
          <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" type="button" id="add_product_attribute">
                New Attribute
          </button>
     </div>
```

When I click on New Attribute button a new section create for me with javascript:

```
let createNewAttr = ({attributes, id}) => {
            return `
                <div id="attribute-${id}" style="margin-top:1.5rem;">
                             <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">عنوان</label>
                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <select name="attributes[${id}][name]" 
                                        onchange="changeAttributeValues(event, ${id});" class="form- 
                                        control">
                                        <option value="">Choose</option>
                                              ${
                attributes.map(function (item) {
                    return `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`
                })
            }
                                </select>
                             </div>
                             <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Value</label>
                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <select name="attributes[${id}][value]" class="attribute-select 
                                                  form-control">
                                        <option value="">Choose</option>
                                    </select>
                             </div>
                     <div class="col-2">
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" 
                        onclick="document.getElementById('attribute-${id}').remove()">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `
        };
```

And this is All of scripts for add new attribute :

```
<script>
        let changeAttributeValues = (event, id) => {
            let valueBox = $(`select[name='attributes[${id}][value]']`);

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/admin/attribute/values',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    name: event.target.value
                }),
                success: function (res) {
                    valueBox.html(`
                        <option selected value="">Choose</option>
                        ${
                        res.data.map(function (item) {
                            return `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`
                        })
                    }
                    `);
                }
            });
        };

        let createNewAttr = ({attributes, id}) => {
            return `
                <div id="attribute-${id}" style="margin-top:1.5rem;">
                             <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Attribute</label>
                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <select name="attributes[${id}][name]" 
                                onchange="changeAttributeValues(event, ${id});" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">Choose</option>
                                              ${
                attributes.map(function (item) {
                    return `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`
                })
            }
                                </select>
                             </div>
                             <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">مقدار</label>
                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <select name="attributes[${id}][value]" class="attribute-select 
                                                  form-control">
                                        <option value="">Choose</option>
                                    </select>
                             </div>
                     <div class="col-2">
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" 
                        onclick="document.getElementById('attribute-${id}').remove()">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `
        };

        $('#add_product_attribute').click(function () {
            let attributesSection = $('#attributes_section');
            let id = attributesSection.children().length;

            let attributes = $('#attributes').data('attributes');

            attributesSection.append(
                createNewAttr({
                    attributes,
                    id
                })
            );

            $('.attribute-select').select2({tags: true});
        });
    </script>
```

This work correctly for me, But when I forgot to fill an required field, these attributes will be gone

How can I keep them ?

UPDATE :
this is codes in my controller :

```
$attributes = collect($data['attributes']);
    $attributes->each(function ($item) use ($product) {
        if (is_null($item['name']) || is_null($item['value'])) return;

        $attr = Attribute::firstOrCreate([
            'name' => $item['name']
        ]);

        $attr_value = $attr->values()->firstOrCreate([
            'value' => $item['value']
        ]);

        $product->attributes()->attach($attr->id, ['value_id' => $attr_value- 
                                                                       >id]);
    });
```

$data comes from validation

Comment: Where is the laraval part of this question? If there isn't any. please untag the laraval and create a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: @mplungjan I update the question, but problem is not in controller, it's about how to keep this data in laravel

Comment: Use Livewire https://laravel-livewire.com/ its way easy and can easily solve your issue with it. @Waltun

Comment: @Emmanuel but I don't use livewire in my application and I don't know about livewire yet